# Show that the linear mapping from $\mathbb {C^3} $ to $\mathbb {C} $ induces a map from space of linear 1-dimensional subspaces of $C^3$ to C

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was going through some lecture notes from linear algebra and there was this statement written that linear mappings from $C^3$ to $C$ induce a map from a space of 1-dimensional linear subspaces of $C^3$ to C. I wanted to show that this statement is true mathematically but I just didn't know where to start studying this map. One way  I think to study linear maps like this one is to study its kernal.  If I let X to be the space of 1-dimensional linear subspaces of $C^3$ to $C$ and let $f$: $C^3$ -> $C$ . $Ker$($f$)= {V ∈ $C^3$ : $f$(V)= $0$ }. I expressed the elements of X space as lines, since f is a linear function it takes subspaces to subspaces and its easier to visualize how linear function on $C^3$ induces a function on X ( probably the induced function is also linear) but i am still confused as to how shall i proceed to show that and what could be the image and preimage of this induced mapping ?

Comment: I would recommend first describing "the space of one-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^3$" and the same thing for $\mathbb{C}$. Note (1) these are two spaces, and you're interested in a map from the first to the second; (2) these won't be vector spaces, so it won't really make sense to say that the induced function is linear or not.

Comment: @ElliotYu that was giving me abit problem describing X so I just assumed the elements of this space are lines for easiness. I am interested more in the restricted map that restricts the domain from $C^3$ to just one dimensional linear subspaces.

Answer (score 2):

Normalization is required. Let $T:\Bbb C^3 \to \Bbb C$ be a linear map, and denote by ${\rm P}(\Bbb C^3)$ the set of all complex lines of $\Bbb C^3$ (this is called a complex projective space). Define $\widetilde{T}:{\rm P}(\Bbb C^3)\to \Bbb C$ by $$\widetilde{T}(\Bbb C v) =\frac{T(v)T(\overline{v})}{\langle v,v\rangle},$$where $v\neq 0$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard Hermitian product in $\Bbb C^3$. Replacing $v$ with $\lambda v$, where $\lambda\neq 0$, produces $|\lambda|^2$ in both numerator and denominator, which is readily canceled --- meaning that $\widetilde{T}$ is well defined. Slightly more abstractly, given $L \in {\rm P}(\Bbb C^3)$, how do you compute $\widetilde{T}(L)$? You **choose** a non-zero $v \in L$ and compute the quantity above, as we have just argued that the choice of non-zero $v\in L$ doesn't matter in the result. If $L\subseteq \ker T$, then $\widetilde{T}(L)=0$.